# Adding new python expressions on QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-custom-function

I just tried creating the following function on the function editor on the select by expression

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Python')
def is_selected(values,feature,parent):
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
return feature.id() in layer.selectedFeaturesIds()
```

However, even if I press the load button, when I go back to the custom , it doesn't list it.

How to add my function?

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but did you click on [New file] button before entering your code into the editor?

Comment: @Kazuhito yes, I now have 3 different scripts on the left side but only the default scratch one appears

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax in last line isn't good... You need to use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).
Try with something like below, it will return a string which is a list of the selected features's id.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Python')
def is_selected(values,feature,parent):
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    return ', '.join([str(id) for id in layer.selectedFeaturesIds()])
```

You have to click on the Load button to add the function in your expressions.

After that, your function will appears in the Python group because of the argument (group='Python') of your decorator.

Comment: Tried you syntax but it still doesn't appear under custom after loading

Comment: @Luffydude "group='Python'" means that the function will appear under the "Python" group, not under the "Custom" group.

Comment: @AndreaGiudiceandrea thanks. seems they've implemented this after I posted this question

Comment: @Luffydude I don't think so. It is by design from the beginning. If you specify "group='Python'", then the custom expression will appear under the "Python" group. If you specify "group='Custom'", then the custom expression will appear under the "Custom" group.

Comment: I meant the is_selected function